# Character clips into the ground when i uncrouch under a platform unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

When ever I crouch under some ground, I clip into the ground after i uncrouch. i followed Brackeys 2d movement tutorial and this is my c# script for the movement. The character controller is a copy from this github link: https://github.com/Brackeys/2D-Character-Controller. The only thing I changed was a line of code I added to fix the animation

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
        
        public CharacterController2D controller;
        public Animator animator;
        public float runSpeed = 40f;

        float horizontalMove = 0f;
        bool jump = false;
        bool crouch = false;

         // Update is called once per frame
         void Update () {

                 horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;


                 animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

                 if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                 {
                       jump = true;
                       animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
                 }
                 
                 if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
                 {
                       crouch = true;
                 } else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
                 {
                    crouch = false;
                 }

          }

          public void OnLanding ()
          {
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
          }
          public void OnCrouching (bool IsCrouching){
            animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", IsCrouching);
          }
          
          void FixedUpdate ()
          {
                   // Move our character
                   controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
                   jump = false;
          }
}
```

Here is an image for my problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zyio.png

Answer (score 0):

Normally while handling jumping you have a groundCheck to see if you are touching the ground in order to be able to jump. Your animation bool achieves a similar result.
You can have a ceiling check which can achieve the same goal. Have a trigger collider positioned at the top of your players head, check if it is triggering with the wall using tags.

```
    public bool CeilingCheck;
    public bool crouch;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = true;
        }
        else if (!CeilingCheck)
        {
            crouch = false;
        }
    }
```

This can be attached to the game Object with the ceiling check collider.

```
public PlayerMovement mainScript;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Level")
    {
        mainScript.CeilingCheck = true;
    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Level")
    {
        mainScript.CeilingCheck = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Christopher. Although your recommended script seems cool, can you please explain what my problem is. Is it my ground check? ceiling check? my colliders? Also I am not handling jumping I am handling crouching. Also I do have a ceiling check (at least i think so) It would help if u were to skip through Brackeys tutorial a little and see a big difference in my code or setup. thx btw